# BAT - Comando para parar vários serviços simultâneos sem aguardar finalizar

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Sou iniciante na area de BAT e estou tentando controlar alguns serviços como parar, desativar, mover para status manual... Estou encontrando dificuldade para parar vários serviços simultâneos e não fazer 1 a 1... o que esta acontecendo atualmente é que desejo parar 5 serviços, porem eles executam e aguardam finalizar para ai sim ir para o próximo. Trecho abaixo.

```batch
net stop Teste1
net stop Teste2
net stop Teste3
net stop Teste4
net stop Teste5...
```

Existe alguma forma de eu forçar para que ele já pule para o próximo sem aguardar o final?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O comando start permite iniciar um comando ou programa sem que seja necessário aguardar o termino do mesmo para dar sequencia em seu código:

```
@echo off
start cmd.exe /c net stop teste1
start cmd.exe /c net stop teste2
start cmd.exe /c net stop teste3
start cmd.exe /c net stop teste4
start cmd.exe /c net stop teste5
exit
```

O bat também deve ser executado como administrador pois é preciso permissões de admin para finalizar \ iniciar serviços.

Comment: Explica direito o que está acontecendo e o que são e o porque o uso desses comandos. Minha tendência é dar +1 para o código só faltou a orientação do porque usar.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para o que estava precisando, muito obrigado Augusto!